# Do not match at all if leading numbers

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I created a small RegEx in order to find some variable names in a string:

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

In my case, a variable can have integers and letters + the underscore character, but it shouldn't start by a number.

The issue is that in this string:

```
"whateverTextBefore,246myVariableName25"
```

It will match myVariableName25, leaving the 246 before. I would like not to match this at all.

I tried this pattern too:

```
([^0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

To specify no leading number, but I get the same result.

So how can I make this RegEx work to just refuse match at all if there are leading numbers?

Note that in the example, it is a comma before, but it could be any specific character, among others:

```
,.<>/?:;'"[]{})(-+=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
\b([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\b
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jV3sY2/1)

Also, note that `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be replaced by `\w`.

```
\b([a-zA-Z]\w+)\b
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jV3sY2/2)

To allow a single alphabet, `+` quantifier can be replaced by `*`.

```
\b([a-zA-Z]\w*)\b
             ^
```

Comment: So quick! Thanks, I didn't know about word boundary. I will keep the long version though as I think it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this!

```
/\b([^,0-9]\w*?)\b/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eU4nP1/1

Don't forget the `g` modifier so it will match multiple results. Every language has a different way to add modifier. This is for PHP.

Don't forget to exclude `,` or it will be included in the result.

Comment: This is not equivalent, I described in the question, it doesn't have to be a comma, it can be any special character